# CloudKit data purged again and now I cannot sort on creationDate

Tags: cloudkit

This morning I suddenly got this error:

> Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=2016 "Field '___createTime'
>   is not marked sortable"

This was caused by this statement:

```
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
```

Going to the CloudKit Dashboard I noticed that all my records were purged and apparently the model was recreated. When clicking on metadata index fields I could see that none of those are sortable anymore. From the Dashboard it's not possible to enable this. Is there any other way to enable this? Or do I just have to add my own sortable date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now a couple of hours later I am able to change the searchable and sortable of these fields. So this was probably a temporary CloudKit Dashboard hickup

Comment: I just had this kind of hickup today. Still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an error today that I didn't get yesterday, so it may be that they are changing things on us...

This is the error I am seeing today:

```
X-MMe-Client-Info/X-Apple-Client-Info header did not meet the minimum build version, rejecting request
```

I haven't made any changes to my code, so it's not me.

I also noticed the records I had stored are gone. I'm wondering if this is normal. I realize it's still in beta, so perhaps it is to be expected.

Comment: I just noticed there is a new beta 4 of Xcode - I have beta 3, so perhaps that is it. Downloading now...

Comment: The update did fix the problem I was seeing with that error. It's working again.

Comment: Yes, there is lot's of inconsistent behaviour

Comment: I noticed that too Edwin. Frustrating at times. :o)